# Is this an application of the Birthday problem?

Tags: probability, computational-complexity

Let's say there is some positive integer n that is somewhere between 0 and N (also a positive integer). I tell the program to start generating random (or pseudo-random) number pairs (modulo N) and check each time if their difference is n. When n is found, program exits.

pseudo code:

```
declare n and give it some value;
declare a;
declare b;

--start
a = random() mod N;
b = random() mod N;

if |a-b| = n
   {
     exit program;
   }
else
   {
     go back to the start line;
   }
```

What is the complexity of such program?

Next, I want to find what is the probability of that n being found after m number of tries (pair difference checks). To make it easier, I reverse the question and ask what is the probability of that n NOT being found after m tries:

(for example, n = 9 and N = 10)

2 = number of pairs that give 9 (I'm checking for absolute values of pair differences)

10^2 = number of all possible pairs

10^2 - 2 = number of pairs that will NOT give 9

So the probability of NOT getting 9 after m tries is: $(\frac{98}{100})^m$

It seems that after around 34 checks I should have about 50% probability of getting 9.

Is my calculation correct? 
Is this an application of the Birthday problem?

Comment: It is not clear when your program stops.

Comment: @Crostul When it finds n.

Comment: What do you mean by the "Birthday Paradox"? If you meant the problem described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem, it is **not** any kind of paradox, it has nothing to do with computational complexity and it is solved by a straightforward calculation.

Comment: @RobArthan I know it's not an actual paradox, it's just that it's sometimes called that. I edited my question to make it clearer that I'm asking about the complexity of the algorithm and I'm asking if there is a relation to the birthday problem because of the way I'm picking random numbers and calculating their difference.

Comment: You have no guarantee that your program will ever reach a state when $|a-b| = n$.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get $a - b \equiv N \mod N$ when $a$ and $b$ are $0 \le a, b < N$ is that $a = b$. Thus the program stops when the same number is generated twice, which happens once in $N^2$ tries.

The [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is that the size of the *set* of values taken independently out of $N$ to get probability $1/2$ of some element repeating is around $\sqrt{N}$, but one would naïvely think it needs to be much larger.

Comment: Sorry but I made a mistake in the pseudo code part. Please see that part again. I'm checking if | a - b | = n.

Answer (score 0):

First i wrote a bit of code in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var calc = new Calculator(100);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("All Differences are {0}", calc.CountAllDifferences()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("All Differences %N = 0 are: {0}", calc.CoundAllDivisibleDifferences()));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    internal class Calculator
    {
        private int n;

        public Calculator(int n)
        {
            this.n = n;
        }

        public int CountAllDifferences()
        {
             HashSet<int> allPossibleDifferences = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
                {
                    allPossibleDifferences.Add(Math.Abs(a - b));
                }
            }
            return allPossibleDifferences.Count;
        }


        public int CoundAllDivisibleDifferences()
        {
            var divisibleDifferences = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(a-b)%n == 0)
                    {
                        divisibleDifferences += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return divisibleDifferences;
        }
    }
}
```

the result is, that there are for N, you will get n possible absolute differences. And you get also n possible diffences, for Math.abs(a-b)%n==0.

In case of n=10, than each time a equals b.

So the complexity could be O(N/2) = O(N) in Big O Notation.